# RBBG BDH Override to get Values in EUR

Tags: r, currency, bloomberg, overriding

```
start.date <- as.Date("2016-05-13")
end.date   <- as.Date("2017-10-18")

conn <- blpConnect()
spxE <- bdh(conn, "SPX Index", "PX_LAST", start.date, end.date, override_fields = "CURRENCY", override_values = "EUR")
spx <- bdh(conn, "SPX Index", "PX_LAST", start.date, end.date)
spx=cbind(spxE, spx)
tail(spx)
```

thats my Code. Output is:

```
                 date PX_LAST       date PX_LAST
2017-10-10 2017-10-10 2550.64 2017-10-10 2550.64
2017-10-11 2017-10-11 2555.24 2017-10-11 2555.24
```

so obviously it didnt work out to get SPX Index calculated in EUR. It works in Excel... any tipps?

Comment: Have you tried with `CRNCY_ADJ_PX_LAST` and `EQY_FUND_CRNCY`?

Comment: Those two are just available for BDP, not for BDH, but thx for your input!

Comment: Oh my bad, I hadn't noticed it was a bdh - have you tried with `FX` instead of `CURRENCY`?

Answer (score 0):

Most fields are not available with overrides to get them in a different currency. This makes sense since it would unnecessarily complicate requests (consider that there are multiple pricing sources for currency pairs). You can always ask for currency the security: DS004 or PR467 and then convert from that currency to Euro. This would be something like:

```
currency <- bdp(conn, "SPX Index","DS004")
currencyPair <- paste(currency, "USD")
ratio <- bdh(conn, currencyPair, start.date, end.date)
```

and then multiply the output of PX_LAST by the ratio. I don't program in r, but the above should be close enough.

Comment: While this seems to be the case with `bdp`, it is certainly possible to choose the currency with `bdh` in the Excel add-in, where you can override the `CURRENCY` field, or supply a parameter `FX=USD` (to translate everything in U.S. dollars)